# Category orphaned when creating subfolder joomla

Tags: joomla

I was in `>Exten >DocMan >Category` and I was created a new subfoler. No problem. Then, I went to the subfolder and tried to create a subfolder under it.

```
Example:          Node Tree:
Animals SM         (A)
.-Mammal M           (B)
..-Domestic CF         (C)
...-Cat F                (D)
...-Dog F                (D)
....-Herders ACE           (E)
....-Sporting BOJ          (E)
....-Terriers PSP          (E)
.....-Cairn ROR              (F)
.....-Pitbull RCF            (F)
.....-Yorkshire RMR          (F)
```

First, I created (E) Terriers PSP.  Checked site, all good.
Then, I created (F) Yorkshire RMR.
(instead of checking the box and hitting "add", I clicked the link *big mistake*)

```
Category Title:  Yorkshire
Category Name: Yorkshire
Parent Item: Mammals (*big mistake*)
Ordering: Mammals (*big mistake*)
```

Now, my whole Mammals folder is GONE.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete your subfolder via the backend or directly in the database?